# Excel VBA object required error with IE automation

Tags: excel, vba

So I have some code to go to a website and then login. Then I need it to go to the password change URL. Sometimes when I run the code, I get the following error:

> Runtime Error 424: Object Required

Sometimes the debugger says it is the first getelementbyid statement, but most times it says the issue is the last three getelementbyid statements. The code is below:

```
 Dim ie As Variant
 Dim strURL As String
 Sub login()


Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
 ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "https://minecraft.net/profile"

While ie.Busy
DoEvents
Wend

ie.document.getElementById("username").Value = "ddd"
ie.document.getElementById("password").Value = "ddddddddddd"

Dim htmlForm As HTMLFormElement
Set htmlForm = ie.document.getElementById("loginForm")
 htmlForm.submit
' **********************************************************************
'IE.Document.getElementById("username").Value = "ddddd"
' IE.Document.getElementById("password").Value = "ddddd"
' IE.Document.getElementById("signin").Click
'**********************************************************************
'Pause while page loads


Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:03 AM#)
ie.navigate "https://minecraft.net/profile/password"

ie.document.getElementById("oldPassword").Value = "oldpass"
ie.document.getElementById("password").Value = "enwapss"
ie.document.getElementById("passwordConfirmation").Value = "enwapss"


Set htmlForm = ie.document.getElementById("loginForm")
htmlForm.submit

 End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that the website isn't in a ready state, as in the site hasn't fully loaded when it's attempting to input the values.

After

> ie.navigate "https://minecraft.net/profile/password"

Try adding

> Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
>                   DoEvents
>               Loop

This will loop until the webpage has loaded similar, to the way you've done it in your above code with

> Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:03 AM#)

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm